# How to declare property in model which is calculated in request?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Running checks in laravel laravel/framework 9.52.5/ nunomaduro/larastan 2.6.0 app  with command

```
./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse
```

I got error line :

Access to an undefined property

```
App\Models\BannerCategory::$banner_clicked_counts_count.
```

Pointing at request :

```
$bannerCategories = BannerCategory
    ::leftJoin((new Banner)->getTable(), (new Banner)->getTable().'.banner_category_id', '=', (new BannerCategory)->getTable() . '.id')
    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
    ->addSelect(['banner_clicked_counts_count' => BannerClickedCount
        ::selectRaw('count(*)')
        ->whereColumn('banners.banner_category_id', 'banner_categories.id')
        ->whereColumn('banner_clicked_counts.banner_id', 'banners.id')
        ->whereRaw("banners.active = true ")

        ->getByCreatedAt($dateStart->startOfDay(), '>=')
        ->getByCreatedAt($dateEnd->endOfDay(), '<=')
        ->getByPageContentId($pageContentId)
        ->getByLocale($locale)
    ])
    ->get();

$seriesData = [];
foreach( $bannerCategories as $bannerCategory ) {
    $seriesData[] = $bannerCategory->banner_clicked_counts_count; // Error pointing at this line
    $labelsData[] = $bannerCategory->name;
}
```

I modified model app/Models/BannerCategory.php as :

```
class BannerCategory extends Model
{
    use HasLocks;
    use Sluggable;
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'banner_categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $bannerClickedCountsCount = 0;
    protected $appends = ['bannerClickedCountsCount'];
...

    function getBannerClickedCountsCount(): int
    {
        \Log::info(varDump($this->bannerClickedCountsCount, ' -1 getBannerClickedCountsCount $this->bannerClickedCountsCount::'));
        return $this->bannerClickedCountsCount;
    }

    function setBannerClickedCountsCount(int $bannerClickedCountsCount)
    {
        \Log::info(varDump($bannerClickedCountsCount, ' -1 setBannerClickedCountsCount $bannerClickedCountsCount::'));
        return $this->bannerClickedCountsCount = $bannerClickedCountsCount;
    }
```

Tracing sql-statement :

```
   SELECT `banner_categories`.*, (  SELECT count(*) 
    FROM `banner_clicked_counts` 
    WHERE `banners`.`banner_category_id` = `banner_categories`.`id`     AND `banner_clicked_counts`.`banner_id` = `banners`.`id`     AND banners.active = true      AND banner_clicked_counts.created_at >= '2023-04-07 00:00:00'     AND banner_clicked_counts.created_at <= '2023-05-07 23:59:59')     AS `bannerClickedCountsCount` 
    FROM `banner_categories` 
    LEFT JOIN `banners` on `banners`.`banner_category_id` = `banner_categories`.`id` 
    ORDER BY `name` asc
```

I see that column bannerClickedCountsCount  has value > 0, but method

```
function getBannerClickedCountsCount(): int
```

returns 0 for all rows(I log this value) .
I suppose I set  $bannerClickedCountsCount value in wrong way. Which way is valid ?

I would like to set it correctly, not use larastan ignore line.

Comment: Snake vs camel case.... anyway use getAttribute function instead of direct access.

Comment: Do you meant that I habve to use $bannerCategory->getAttribute('bannerClickedCountsCount');
and DO NOT DEFINE any $bannerClickedCountsCount var in model ?

Comment: Yes. but be consistent. snake or camel both in sql and code.

Comment: Could you please write it as answer and I will accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $model->getAttribute('attribute');
You started the query as BannerCategory::leftJoin that should retrieve an instance of BannerCategory, even if that is not exactly what it contains.

```
$bannerCategories = BannerCategory
::leftJoin((new Banner)->getTable(), (new Banner)->getTable().'.banner_category_id', '=', (new BannerCategory)->getTable() . '.id')
->orderBy('name', 'asc')
->addSelect(['banner_clicked_counts_count' => BannerClickedCount
    ::selectRaw('count(*)')
    ->whereColumn('banners.banner_category_id', 'banner_categories.id')
    ->whereColumn('banner_clicked_counts.banner_id', 'banners.id')
    ->whereRaw("banners.active = true ")

    ->getByCreatedAt($dateStart->startOfDay(), '>=')
    ->getByCreatedAt($dateEnd->endOfDay(), '<=')
    ->getByPageContentId($pageContentId)
    ->getByLocale($locale)
])
->get();

$seriesData = [];
foreach( $bannerCategories as $bannerCategory ) {
    $seriesData[] = $bannerCategory->getAttribute('banner_clicked_counts_count');
    $labelsData[] = $bannerCategory->name;
}
```